# Visual Studio 2019 Nuget cannot find a package

Tags: nuget, visual-studio-2019

My packages.config has this entry:

```
<package id="xxxxxx" version="3.0.0" allowedVersions="[3.0,3.3)" targetFramework="net452">
```

Now there is no package xxxxxxx at version 3.0.0 (there might have been, once upon a time), but I am allowing anything between 3.0 and 3.3.  I do have a package at 3.1.0, and I expected that nuget would find that one and pick it up, but I get the error

> Unable to find version '3.0.0' of package xxxxxxxx

Questions:

1. Why does nuget not say, "oh I can't find 3.0.0 but I'm allowed to use anything from 3.0 to 3.3 and I have 3.1.0.  I'll use that!"
2. What is the correct config to use to make it pick up the highest available version in the allowed range?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In `packages.config`, every dependency is listed with an exact
>   `version` attribute that's used when restoring packages. The
>   `allowedVersions` attribute is used only during update operations to
>   constrain the versions to which the package might be updated.

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/concepts/package-versioning#references-in-project-files-packagereference

If you want to use ranges in your project, you will have to switch to References in project files (PackageReference), but keep in mind:

> NuGet 2.8.x and earlier chooses the latest available package version
>   when resolving a dependency, whereas NuGet 3.x and later chooses the
>   lowest package version.

Option to always resolve to highest version was proposed and rejected: https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/1192

Comment: aha, I see it now.  I fixed package config, but the project cannot find the package,  Is there an easy way to sync .csproj with packages.config?

Comment: You cannot use both package.config and PackageReferences. You have to pick one. There is one time migration from package.config to PackageReferences described in here: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/nuget/migrate-packages-config-to-package-reference/

Comment: But we've been using both for years now.  It does work, just not nicely.  still I'll follow up on that link

Comment: Did that in a new branch.  WHen done, nuget package manager doesn't show anything at all